# Error message in R after conducting ANOVA

Tags: r, error-handling, anova, covariance-matrix

I want to conduct a mixed ANOVA in R with three factors (factor group and age_group are between subjects, factor test_interval is within subject) and used the aov-function of the "car" package. So the Model I generated is:

```r
Model <- aov(Imitationscore ~ age_group * Group * test_interval + Error(Code/test_interval) + age_group * Group, data = Data)
```

The creation of the model didn´t cause any problems in R, but after I wanted to display the model with the instruction:

```r
Anova(Model)
```

R showed the following error message:

```r
Error in vcov.default(mod, complete = FALSE) : 
  object does not have variance-covariance matrix
```

I know what a variance-covariance matrix is, but i don´t know exactly how to interpret that message?
Or do I conduct a three-way Anova with repeated measurements with a completely different function and that´s the reason why R showed that message?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.  Here, as well as your code, we need to see enough of your data to reproduce the problem.